# Flutter CachedNetworkImage doesn't work for App downloaded from playstore, stuck on placeholder

Tags: android, flutter, image-loading

I'm using CachedNetworkImage in my app and it works fine when I run it in debug or release on Android, however when I upload the aab to the Play Store and download the app from the Play Store, the image is just stuck on the placeholder.

Here's how I'm using it in the app. Note that I use a Text widget for the placeholder and the error so that I can visually debug any issues on the release version:

```
child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            url != null
                ? CachedNetworkImage(
              imageUrl: url,
              errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Text("$error"),
              placeholder: (context, url) => Text("Loading $url"),
              imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 150,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(image: imageProvider, fit: BoxFit.fitWidth),
                ),
              ),
            )
                : Container(),
```

It just stays on the placeholder and looks like this
[image: It just stays on the placeholder and looks like this]

I'm using the latest version of cached_network_image in the pubspec:

```
cached_network_image: ^2.4.1
```

Here's what I've tried so far to help narrow down the problem:

1. Using `Image.network(url)` instead of CachedNetworkImage. The images load fine when I do this, so I know it's not a problem with the internet or the url.
2. Running a release build on the device using `flutter run --release`. This works fine, the images load correctly.
3. Trying out multiple devices. I tried using a Samsung Galaxy 8 on Android 8 and a Pixel 2xl on Android 11. Both work fine with debug builds and release builds, but not when downloaded from the Play Store.
4. Making sure the URL is publicly accessible and that internet permissions are enabled. The app is able to load other content from the internet fine and the image url is on a public domain.

Comment: do you use firebase? if so try to assign the sha1 of your google play console inside firebase.
i faced the same problem for my widgets that were depended on firebase, and also cachedNetwork image.

Comment: Oh I do and that would make sense since since I enabled Google Play signing so it would have a different sha1 than what I set in initially set Firebase up with. I had kind of ruled it out though since it is fetching other data from Cloud Firestore works fine and was also not loading a public url, but I'll try it and see how it goes. Thanks so much @Mahdi-Jafaree!

Comment: share your result after trying to solve for further or accepting my comment as answer :)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to change anything. It's really strange that `Image.network` works fine but `CachedNetworkImage` doesn't.

Comment: Also thinking about it more, it should transition to the error Text widget if that were the case. I don't understand why it's just stuck on the placeholder widget.

Comment: Ah just found this issue on github, seems I'm not the only one. Looks like it's due to proguard obfuscation with the sqflite library  https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter_cached_network_image/issues/497. Will try out their workarounds

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I ended up finding the solution in the github issues here github.com/Baseflow/flutter_cached_network_image/issues/497. Turns out it is a proguard issue with the sqflite library that CachedNetworkImage uses. The solution, until they fix it in the library, is to add a the default proguard file to the build.gradle file:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true // Add these lines
            shrinkResources true // Add these lines
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt') // Add these lines
        }
    }
```

I'm actually really surprised no one else has posted about this on SO that I could find, seems like a major breaking change to the library.

Comment: This response is extremely helpful. Would never have found this myself. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Wow this solution fix also another issue given by Image Picker github: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/75966#issuecomment-778622767

Comment: what do you put in `proguard-android-optimize.txt` and where do you save it?

Comment: @LeeProbert I think it's added automatically to your project when you created the flutter project. Try searching for the filename to see if it's in your project already.

Comment: not working for me, I just see a cross, any other ideas?